# Tweet new post on submit

Tags: php, jquery, twitter

Is it possible to add some code that will tweet a message (or would offer to post a tweet) once a user submit a form yo post a message on my site.

Do I need to point it to my tweet account? Just trying the process.

I use PHP and jQuery on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Yes, you do need to point it to some twitter account in your control (you could create a new one for your app/website).
See the [twitter php libs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php).